# How do I make and parse a raw SQL query with Diesel?

Tags: mysql, rust, rust-diesel

I'm testing out Rust using the Rocket framework. For the database, I'm using Diesel to interact with my MySQL database.

Following a few examples, there are a lot of things happening under the hood. I've got a MySQL Database running with a populated tables that I'd like to make a raw query on.

The below code works:

```
use diesel::{prelude::*};

mod schema {
    table! {
        organization {
            id -> Nullable<Integer>,
            name -> Text,
            country -> Text,
        }
    }
}

use self::schema::organization;
use self::schema::organization::dsl::{organization as all_orgs};

#[table_name="organization"]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Queryable, Insertable, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Organization {
    pub id: Option<i32>,
    pub name: String,
    pub country: String
}

impl Organization {
    pub fn all(conn: &MysqlConnection) -> Vec<Organization> {
        all_orgs.order(organization).load::<Organization>(conn).unwrap()
    }
}
```

However, I do not need to order by anything. In fact, I'd just like to make a raw query as `SELECT id, name, country FROM organization` and call it a day.

I've attempted the below after looking at [Diesel documentation](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/fn.sql_query.html) and found something called `sql_query`.

My code now looks like:

```
use diesel::{prelude::*, sql_query};

mod schema {
    table! {
        organization {
            id -> Nullable<Integer>,
            name -> Text,
            country -> Text,
        }
    }
}

use self::schema::organization;

#[table_name="organization"]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Queryable, Insertable, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Organization {
    pub id: Option<i32>,
    pub name: String,
    pub country: String
}

impl Organization {
    pub fn all(conn: &MysqlConnection) -> Vec<Organization> {
         sql_query("SELECT id, name, country FROM organization")
            .load(&conn).unwrap()
    }
}
```

However, upon doing `cargo run` on on this change, I am faced with:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&diesel::MysqlConnection: diesel::Connection` is not satisfied
  --> src/org.rs:26:19
   |
26 |             .load(&conn).unwrap()
   |                   -^^^^
   |                   |
   |                   the trait `diesel::Connection` is not implemented for `&diesel::MysqlConnection`
   |                   help: consider removing the leading `&`-reference
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <diesel::MysqlConnection as diesel::Connection>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<&diesel::MysqlConnection, _>` for `SqlQuery`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Organization: QueryableByName<_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/org.rs:26:14
   |
26 |             .load(&conn).unwrap()
   |              ^^^^ the trait `QueryableByName<_>` is not implemented for `Organization`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<&diesel::MysqlConnection, Organization>` for `SqlQuery`
```

How do I satisfy these errors, while being allowed to do a raw SQL query and parse it correctly from the function, given the input parameters and desired output?

Comment: *I do not need to order by anything* — why not remove the `.order(organization)` line then?

Comment: Oh wow, it was that simple.. I was overthinking it. Thank you for the help, please do answer the question and I'll accept!

Comment: That doesn't answer your **question** though. It only solves your problem.

Answer (score 7):

To solve your problem, you can remove the `.order(organization)` to avoid performing a sort.

To answer the question explicitly asked: The error messages mention two problems:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&diesel::MysqlConnection: diesel::Connection` is not satisfied
  --> src/org.rs:26:19
   |
26 |             .load(&conn).unwrap()
   |                   -^^^^
   |                   |
   |                   the trait `diesel::Connection` is not implemented for `&diesel::MysqlConnection`
   |                   help: consider removing the leading `&`-reference
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <diesel::MysqlConnection as diesel::Connection>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<&diesel::MysqlConnection, _>` for `SqlQuery`
```

This one is easy to fix: do what the compiler suggests and remove the leading `&` reference for your call to `.load(&conn)`.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Organization: QueryableByName<_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/org.rs:26:14
   |
26 |             .load(&conn).unwrap()
   |              ^^^^ the trait `QueryableByName<_>` is not implemented for `Organization`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<&diesel::MysqlConnection, Organization>` for `SqlQuery`
```

This one points to the actual problem that disallows loading results in your `Organization` struct. Diesel needs to be told how to construct your `Organization` struct out of the query response. Diesel provides 2 traits for this :

- [`Queryable`](http://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/deserialize/trait.Queryable.html) for constructing a struct out of the result of a type safe query (== a query build by using the dsl provided by diesel, so that it is checked at compile time). `
- [`QueryableByName`](http://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/deserialize/trait.QueryableByName.html) to construct a struct out of the result of a non-type  safe query (so basically a query executed via `diesel::sql_query`)

As the error message mentions, your struct does not implement `QueryableByName`, which is required to load the result of `diesel::sql_query` in that struct. You need to implement this trait. The easiest option is to use the `derive` provided by Diesel.

A fixed version of your code would look like this then:

```rust
use diesel::{prelude::*, sql_query};

mod schema {
    table! {
        organization {
            id -> Nullable<Integer>,
            name -> Text,
            country -> Text,
        }
    }
}

use self::schema::organization;

#[table_name="organization"]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Queryable, QueryableByName, Insertable, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Organization {
    pub id: Option<i32>,
    pub name: String,
    pub country: String
}

impl Organization {
    pub fn all(conn: &MysqlConnection) -> Vec<Organization> {
         sql_query("SELECT id, name, country FROM organization")
            .load(&conn).unwrap()
    }
}
```